# mysql query fails when using OR column LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

I get a "query failed" message when I use below PHP in a web page but if I remove `OR column2 LIKE '%$searchterm%'` from the query it works fine. I already tried Googling the issue and looked in a for dummies manual. The database table definitely contains the search term in column_2.

```
/* send this query to MySQL database */
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_1 LIKE '%$searchterm%' OR desc LIKE '%$searchterm%'";

/* process query results */
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query) or die ("query failed");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

extract($row);

/* create HTML for web broswer to see */
echo "Column 1 value: $column_1<br><br>";
echo "Column 2 value: $column_2<br><br>";
echo "Column 3 value: $column_3<br><br>";
```

Comment: Are there messages in the Apache error log showing up when the query fails? "query failed" isn't much to go on.

Comment: What's the query actually end up as (`echo $query;`)? It's possible you're not escaping `$searchterm` so it breaks the query. If that's the case, beware of SQL injection, too.

Comment: Check if you are escaping $searchterm correctly. You can var_dump($result) to see the issue.

Comment: Try (if possible) to execute this sql in phpmyadmin. It will show you an error description ..

Comment: Fyi, you should use prepared statements instead of string interpolation and escaping.

Comment: Try `or die(mysql_error())` to see the generic mysql error - which often tells you what is amiss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution! The query needed backticks around the object names to the left of the `OR` statement while the other object names needed straight-up single-quote marks.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column_1` LIKE '%$searchterm%' OR 'column_2' LIKE '%$searchterm%'";
```

I saw the backticks when using phpMyAdmin to translate the query into PHP code but had to ignore the part where backslashes were added as in `\'%$searchterm%\'`. So the translation tool led me to a solution but I don't see a reason for those backslashes.

Also, simpler queries with no `OR` statement worked fine with no backticks and minimal quote marks but I don't see why `OR` would invoke the backticks rule.

Comment: The backticks are only necessary when you use reserved keywords. So don't call your table `table`. If it only broke after adding the `OR` your second column has a name causing the problem.

Comment: Consider renaming it to `description` - then you don't need the backticks.

Comment: You are spot on. The name of column_2 in my actual query uses one of the [reserved MySQL words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html) 'desc'. In the interest of keeping things simple I didn't display my actual query on this forum but I see the value now of showing it. @ThiefMaster

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_1 LIKE '%$searchterm%' UNION SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_2 LIKE '%$searchterm%'";
```